# Octave: Save a table inside a table

Tags: arrays, octave

I am trying to save an array inside a table and i get this error: ***nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x4)***

I have a function running which produces an array of 1 row and 4 columns. For example:

W =   0.32574   0.21354   0.10639   0.35433

What I am trying to do is save all the results that are being generated from the loops. What I am doing is this (for N=4):

```
for m=1:15
  W(m)=weights(N) # N=the number of columns it is going to generate
endfor
```

My function looks like this: (e.g criteria=4)

```
function W=weights(criteria)

W=zeros(1,criteria); #fill the table with zeros
x=rand(1,criteria); #Random numbers are generated, range=[0,1] 
sumx=sum(x); #Sum of all random numbers
factorsumx=1/sumx; #calculate the factor
W=x.*factorsumx; #Random numbers are multiplied with 1/sumx
finalsum=sum(W); #FinalSum is to confirm that the sum of weights is always equal to 1




endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `op2 is 1x4` you need `op1` of same size

```
N=4;
w=zeros(15,N);

for m=1:15
  W(m,1:N)=weights(N) # N=the number of columns it is going to generate
endfor
```